# How to properly link cuda header file with device functions?

Tags: c++, cuda, linker, gpgpu, nvidia

I'm trying to decouple my code a bit and something fails. Compilation error:

```
error: calling a __host__ function("DecoupledCallGpu") from a __global__ function("kernel") is not allowed
```

Code excerpt:

**main.c** (has a call to cuda host function):

```
#include "cuda_compuations.h"
...
ComputeSomething(&var1,&var2);
...
```

**cuda_computations.cu** (has kernel, host master functions and includes header which has device unctions):

```
#include "cuda_computations.h"
#include "decoupled_functions.cuh"
...
__global__ void kernel(){
...
DecoupledCallGpu(&var_kernel);
}

void ComputeSomething(int *var1, int *var2){
//allocate memory and etc..
...
kernel<<<20,512>>>();
//cleanup
...
}
```

**decoupled_functions.cuh**:

```
#ifndef _DECOUPLEDFUNCTIONS_H_
#define _DECOUPLEDFUNCTIONS_H_

void DecoupledCallGpu(int *var);

#endif
```

**decoupled_functions.cu:**

```
#include "decoupled_functions.cuh"

__device__ void DecoupledCallGpu(int *var){
  *var=0;
}

#endif
```

**Compilation:**

nvcc -g --ptxas-options=-v -arch=sm_30 -c cuda_computations.cu -o cuda_computations.o -lcudart

**Question**: why is it that the `DecoupledCallGpu` is called from host function and not a kernel as it was supposed to?

P.S.: I can share the actual code behind it if you need me to.

Comment: Well, in all those code snippets you've showwn niether "ComputeDensityGpu" nor "DoColision", which were the actual functions listed in the error message.  So you leave us guessing.  But it looks to me like your `DecoupledCallGpu` prototype in `decoupled_functions.cuh` is missing the `__device__` decorator.  And separating the compilation of a device function from the compilation unit where it is invoked will probably mean that you have to use [separate compilation and linking](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `__device__` decorator to the prototype in `decoupled_functions.cuh`.  That should take care of the error message you are seeing.

Then you'll need to use [separate compilation and linking](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) amongst your modules.  So instead of compiling with `-c` compile with `-dc`.  And your link command will need to be modified.  A basic example is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples).

Your question is a bit confusing:

> Question: why is it that the DecoupledCallGpu is called from host function and not a kernel as it was supposed to?

I can't tell if you're tripping over english or if there is a misunderstanding here.  The actual error message states:

> error: calling a `__host__` function("DecoupledCallGpu") from a `__global__` function("kernel") is not allowed

This is arising due to the fact that *within the compilation unit* (ie. within the module, within the file that is being compiled, ie. cuda_computations.cu), the only description of the function `DecoupledCallGpu()` is that which is provided in the prototype in the header:

```
void DecoupledCallGpu(int *var);
```

This prototype indicates an *undecorated* function in CUDA C, and such functions are [equivalent to](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#host) `__host__` (only) decorated functions:

```
__host__ void DecoupledCallGpu(int *var);
```

That compilation unit has no knowledge of what is actually in decoupled_functions.cu.

Therefore, when you have kernel code like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(){       //<- __global__ function
...
DecoupledCallGpu(&var_kernel);  //<- appears as a __host__ function to compiler
}
```

the compiler thinks you are trying to call a `__host__` function from a `__global__` function, which is illegal.

Comment: For Visual Studio users, this option translates to changing "Generate relocatable device code" to "Yes" in CUDA C++ options tab. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258292/6734314