# Visual Studio MSB3721 error when compiling a __device__ function call from another file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I'm trying to compile a CUDA project which gives a 255 error as soon as I try to run a function defined in a separate .cu file

This is where the main kernel is defined

```
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <ctime>

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Scene.cuh"

__global__ void fill(float *c, Scene* scene)
{
    int index = blockIdx.y * blockDim.x * blockDim.y * gridDim.x +
                threadIdx.y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x +
                blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


    // this is the line which gives the compilation error
    float3 result = scene->computeRayFromIndex(index);

    c[index * 4 + 0] += 1.0f; 
    c[index * 4 + 1] += 1.0f;
    c[index * 4 + 2] += 1.0f; 
    c[index * 4 + 3] += 1.0f;
}
```

Here is scene.cuh

```
#ifndef Scene_h
#define Scene_h

#include "cuda_runtime.h"

class Scene {

public:
    Scene();

    __host__ __device__ float3 computeRayFromIndex(int);

    int width;
    int height;

    int cameraType;

    private:

};

#endif
```

And scene.cu

```
#include "Scene.cuh"

Scene::Scene() {

}

__host__ __device__ float3 Scene::computeRayFromIndex(int pixelIndex) {
    float3 test;
    return test;
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2013 and I'm adding the cuda files to my project as usual from the menu

This is the compilation error

```
Error   10  error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\fillRandomTexture.cu.obj "D:\CUDA\projects\vRay\vRay\fillRandomTexture.cu"" exited with code 255.
```

The project builds and runs fine if I comment out

```
float3 result = scene->computeRayFromIndex(index);
```

In the main kernel file

Comment: probably you have not enabled [relocatable device code and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459495) in your CUDA project.  Anyway, if you don't want to be pulling your hair out with CUDA projects, increase the verbosity level in visual studio (google how to do that) so that you get more than just this cryptic error.  There should be an instructive error indicated in your compile output from `nvcc` immediately prior to this (something like this: `ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN5Scene19computeRayFromIndexEi'
`).   If not, your verbosity level is too low.

Comment: You can turn on relocatable device code in your project through the project properties as indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/3.2/Content/CUDA_Properties_Config.htm)

Comment: Which is what I did and it worked, also I've set the debug output to verbose and clearly showed the linking error, if you reformat your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CUDA, when we want to call a device code function from another device code function, and those two device code functions are in separate compilation units, it's necessary to enable [relocatable device code generation and linking](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) when compiling such a project.

In visual studio, this can be set for the entire project from the project properties page, as indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/3.2/Content/CUDA_Properties_Config.htm):

[image]

Also, when working with visual studio and CUDA, the error "MSB3721" is a non-specific error from visual studio indicating "I ran `nvcc` and it returned an error".  However, the actual error from `nvcc` should occur prior to this.  If you don't see it in the compile output window immediately prior to the "MSB3721" error, then your verbosity level is too low.  You can increase it, and the exact method to do so will vary slightly by VS version so I recommend doing a search for how to do that, for your specific version.